# Gallery Selected Item not being highlighted?

Tags: android, gallery

normally the selected item in the Gallery is brighter than the other view that arent selected. but in my Gallery all the images are dark, even the selected image.
How can I make the selected item in the Gallery brighter than the other?

GetView:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view_infalter = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.imageadapter_custom_image, null);
    i = (ImageView) view_infalter.findViewById(R.id.ImageAdapter_imageView);

    i.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageIds[position]));
    i.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);

    return i;
}
```

Custom_image.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ImageAdapter_imageView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" 
    ></ImageView>     

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During focus/selection bacckground color of focused view will be changed , but here imageView have fill_parent width and height and FitXY so no room for background to reflect this selection .
so set paddind to imageView will be enough .

if still prob. persist  create a selector in drawable and set it to parentLayout of viewChild .

Comment: instead of just down vote, explanation about what more you are expecting might help you to get solution .